# Remove text from excel cell before first occurance of special character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have string like this -

```
D:\Project\Feature\branch\Main\Databases\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\sp_SampleSP.sql
```

Want to remove all text before "sp_SampleSP.sql". I have tried with Left formula in excel still not able to find solution.

I want output like this:`sp_SampleSP.sql`

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me

Comment: good to hear. and good luck